# What should I use instead of deprecated mondrian.olap.Connection::execute?

Tags: mdx, olap, mondrian, olap4j

So I am trying to use Mondrian 3.14 in Java 1.8, so I did something like this :

```
String catalogFilePath = "<path>/mdx_schema.xml";
String connectUrl = "Provider=mondrian;" +
            "Jdbc=jdbc:postgresql://example.com:5432/database?user=user&password=pass;" +
            "JdbcDrivers=org.postgresql.Driver;" +
            "Catalog=file:" + catalogFilePath + ";";
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectUrl, null);

String qs = "<query>";
Query q = connection.parseQuery(qs);
Result r = connection.execute(q);
```

However, as stated [here](https://mondrian.pentaho.com/api/mondrian/olap/Connection.html#execute(mondrian.olap.Query)), `Connection::execute` is deprecated :

> Deprecated. This method is deprecated and will be removed in mondrian-4.0. It operates by internally creating a statement. Better to use olap4j and explicitly create a statement.

So, what should I use in olap to execute the query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I actually found the answer [here](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/198679-OLAP4J-Connection-SLOW/) :

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import org.olap4j.CellSet;
import org.olap4j.OlapConnection;
import org.olap4j.OlapStatement;
import org.olap4j.OlapWrapper;
import org.olap4j.layout.RectangularCellSetFormatter;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver");

    String catalogFilePath = "<path>/mdx_schema.xml";
    String connectUrl = "jdbc:mondrian:" +
    "Jdbc=jdbc:postgresql://example.com:5432/database?user=user&password=pass;" +
    "JdbcDrivers=org.postgresql.Driver;" +
    "Catalog=file:" + catalogFilePath + ";";

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectUrl);
    OlapWrapper wrapper = (OlapWrapper) connection;
    OlapConnection olapConnection = wrapper.unwrap(OlapConnection.class);
    OlapStatement statement = olapConnection.createStatement();

    String qs = "<query>";

    CellSet cellSet = statement.executeOlapQuery(qs);

    RectangularCellSetFormatter formatter = new RectangularCellSetFormatter(false);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    formatter.format(cellSet, writer);
    writer.flush();

    connection.close();
}
```